# Poincaré inequality for Fractionnal Sobolev space

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Is there a sort of Poincaré's inequality for Fractional Sobolev space ?

Something as
$$\left\|u-\frac{1}{|\Omega |}\int_\Omega u\right\|_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}\leq C[u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}\ \ ?$$

Where $$[u]_{W^{s,p}(\Omega )}=\iint_{\Omega ^2}\frac{|u(x)-u(y)|^p}{|x-y|^{sp+n}}dxdy.$$

Comment: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1104.4345.pdf the theorem 6.5 may help.

Comment: @Cuteboy: thanks, I know this theorem, but unfortunately, it doesn't help.

Comment: It depends on the domain $\Omega$: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.04227.pdf

Comment: @Siminore: it's perfect, thanks a lot for the link :-)

Comment: You probably meant to write $\| \cdot \|_{L^p(\Omega)}$ instead of $W^{s,p}$?

Comment: @idm Hello, did you solve your problem?

Comment: @avati91: Yes and the formula I gave is the right one.

Comment: @idm are you familiar with fractional Sobolev spaces then? Does this inequality look true to you https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2951520/fractional-hardy-inequality ?

Comment: @avati91: Sorry, I have no idea. I wouldn't be surprised that is doesn't hold as written. But I can't find a counter example, I to be honest, I don't really know.