# Fractional Hardy inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, sobolev-spaces, fractional-sobolev-spaces

From classic literature, I know the following result.

> Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^d$ be a bounded open set of class $C^1$.
>   Then there exists $C>0$ such that \begin{equation}\label{1} \|\frac{u}{d}
>  \|_{L^2(\Omega)}\le C\|\nabla u\|_{L^2(\Omega)}\qquad \forall\ u \in
>  H^1_0(\Omega), \end{equation} where
>   $d(x):=\operatorname{dist}(x,\partial\Omega)$.

I am wondering if a fractional order equivalent of the previous result holds, namely
$$
\|\frac{u}{d}
 \|_{H^s(\Omega)}\le C\|\nabla u\|_{H^s(\Omega)}\qquad \forall\ u \in
 H^1_0(\Omega)\cap H^2(\Omega),
$$
for every $0\le s<\frac{1}{2}$.

Does anyone have any ideas or counterexamples?

Thanks!